# How do I reach out to my manager on the first day?

Tags: software-industry, email, first-job

My first day at work is coming up soon and I would like to know how to reach out to my manager and tell him that I would be on campus on the said date and would love to have 1:1 with him. I am a graduate student just entering professional life thank you for your help!

Comment: See what you wrote there? Say that.

Comment: Is there any reason you feel your manager may be too busy or has so many people that report to him that he isn't interested in anything one on one?

Comment: You think you manager does not know where you are going to be on your first day of work?

Comment: @JeffO I am not sure about that. I know there is an orientation and throngs of NCGs will be there.

Comment: @Blam I dont know where he will be.

Comment: So?  You think your manager does not know where YOU are going to be on your first day of work?

Comment: It's not your job to manage your manager.  Why would you know where he will be?

Comment: Why is there a down vote for this? I believe this is a proper question in this forum. I cant help if the question is misinterpreted by a couple of users. I wanted to know how to politely introduce myself to my manager who I havent spoken to for a long time after the interview. My intention is not to manage my manager and I know he knows where I will be, I just wanted to have a face-to-face with him and needed to know the appropriate language for the email to get that going. I have also accepted an answer as the right one. Thank you.

Comment: @TheGrimCoder I think the downvotes are people who would assume that your manager will ensure you will have everything arranged for you to settle in and orient.  Normally managers should have this coverred but it still doesn't hurt to take initiative in reaching out.  If your manager doesn't feel arranging a 1-on-1 is necessary or appropriate, they will tell you so.

Comment: I don't think I've  ever not met the manager on my first day... its usually upon the to introduce you to the team, at the very least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

Dear [name]

I will be on campus on the [date] and would love to have 1:1 with you. I am just entering professional life and would like a chance to set my expectations. Thank you for your help!

Sincerely
TheGrimCoder

Comment: Never use "love to" in business correspondent.  And avoid '!' !